# Move image from gallery to aplication protected folder in java android

Tags: java, android, imageview

When the user selects an image from gallery, it becomes visible in an ImageView and its directory is saved. If the image is deleted the directory will be null, crashing the app. I want to take the image and move it to a secrect/protected folder only visible by the application. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's Base64 Android class:

`String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);`

convert your image into a byte array though. Here's an example:

`Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object

byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();`

Have a look here : http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-base64-encode-decode-android.html

or just google on how to use Base64 and then store the string in your private/protected application area.